ISRG Root X1 (Android Googlebot)
Received this message from Cloudflare:
After September 9th, all Let’s Encrypt certificates issued through Cloudflare will start using the ISRG Root X1 chain resulting in a reduction of device compatibility. This will mainly impact connections from old Android devices (version 7.1.1 and earlier). To prevent this impact, we recommend re-issuing your advanced certificates with a different CA, such as Google Trust Services.
The question is Googlebot mobile uses the user-agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.6533.99 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
The question I have will crawls from Googlebot also be affected as Google won't be able to connect via https?
Thank you.

Odds that the Googlebot for mobile is actually running on a Nexus 5X running Android 6.0.1 as zero. I think you don't have to worry about that one.

The September date have to be interpreted in a different way as most user do: This is the last day a valid certificate using the ISRG Root X1 chain can be found in the wild. Final migration has started 90 days before and most certs have been migrated way earlier. Effectively nearly all let's encrypt certs had been switched months ago to the new chain. See  https://android.stackexchange.com/q/256772/2241
